# Timepicker in twitter bootstrap modal not receiving clicks

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery, timepicker

I'm trying to use [jquery-timepicker](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker) along with bootstrap. It works fine, unless the timepicker input is inside a bootstrap modal.

The time list is not getting the click events, though visually everything looks fine (it has higher z-index than the modal and the overlay. Scrolling and hover styles work fine).

The issue has been reproduced at http://jsfiddle.net/Qkgxu/1/

Comment: this is an interesting issue, will definitely look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a [bug](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker/issues/36) with the timepicker and it has been [fixed now](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker/commit/995a8d915bd9b6e32d26dbbdc7c95579da57349a).

Answer (score 0):

this is a problem with timepicker and modals.

The solution that I found is:

Look for showWidget function, inside this function you must replace

```
this.$element.trigger('show');
```

with this

```
if (this.template === 'modal) {
   this.$element.trigger('show');
}
```